# upload_to and storage not working in Django 4.1

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have just upgrade my Django from 2.x to 4.x. I had a function that not working correctly. I have been trying so many things but still not able to figure it out. So i need some help

```
file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=get_file_path,
        storage=AbsolutePathStorage(),
        max_length=500,
    )
```

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


class AbsolutePathStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    """Storage that allows storing files given absolute paths."""

    def path(self, name: str) -> str:
        """Override path validation to allow absolute paths."""
        # Return name if it's a absolute path.
        if name.startswith("/"):
            return name

        # Return regular joined path if this is a relative path.
        return super().path(name)
```

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    root_data = '/data'
    return os.path.join(root_data, instance.relative_path)
```

So before upgrading Django, the file is uploaded to the upload_to folder ( outside of MEDIA_ROOT). Everything is working fine. But after i upgraded Django to 4.1. Its not working anymore and complaining about:

```
The joined path (upload_to) is located outside of the base path component (MEDIA_ROOT ).
```

Any idea ?

Thank you.

//----------------------- UPDATE ------------------------------

Actually, the file is uploaded correctly to the upload_to path. But its not able to save the path to the database. so this is probably where the issue occur.

Comment: from where did you get `get_file_path` ? add the code related to it

Comment: @moim i have updated my question to included get_file_path.

Comment: @monim so basically, the upload_to would be something like: `/data/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.zip` as an example.

Comment: i dont have the issue that upload outside of MEDIA_ROOT until upgrade Django to this new version. :(

Answer (score 0):

You call `super().path()` in your function, which is where this error is raised.

```
class AbsolutePathStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    ...

class FileSystemStorage:
    def path(self, name):
        return safe_join(self.location, name) # safe_join raises the error
```

If your `upload_to` function returns an absolute path, then it looks like you can just use the name as-is and no logic is need in the `name()` function.  The `assert` here is just a sanity check.

```
class AbsolutePathStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def path(self, name: str) -> str:
        assert name.startswith("/"), f"Path was not absolute: {name}"
        return name
```